# Is it possible to paste at the top-left corner in Krita?

Tags: krita, copy-and-paste

I have been porting images over to Krita from other places on occasion, or copying a layer, editing in another program, and pasting it back into Krita. Every pasted image is placed at the cursor position instead of the top-left corner as I'd normally expect.

I cannot find any information about this online or in the bug tracker. Is it possible to change this behavior so that images pasted in Krita are always placed at the top-left corner instead of the mouse position?

Comment: Ctrl+Alt+V pastes at the cursor position. Use Ctrl+V to paste in the middle of the image. If you have Snap to Grid ON there's no problem to move the pasted layer exactly to the corner with the move tool. There's no need to move if the pasted layer has the same pixel dimensions as the image.

Comment: @user287001 Tested. It's opposite; Ctrl+V pastes at cursor. I should be doing Ctrl+Alt+V to get the behavior you describe, which is working as expected.

Comment: Quite a confusing spectacle https://i.stack.imgur.com/tsYkh.jpg I would say. Seemingly Krita exists as different versions. I have 4.1.5 Here Ctrl+V pastes in the middle.

Comment: @user287001 4.2.8 for me, and my shortcuts in edit are exact opposite of your screenshot. I didn't override it. Strange; maybe it was recently changed.

Answer (score 1):

Collected from comments:

Ctrl+V affects in questioner's Krita version differently than in earlier versions. It pastes at the cursor position. Ctrl+Alt+V pastes in the middle of the image. Corners fit as wanted if the pasted layer has same pixel dimensions than the image canvas.

If the pasted layer is smaller it can be placed perfectly to a corner with the Move tool if Snap to Grid in ON.

The default shortcuts for pasting in Krita 4.1.5 are these:

[image]

They are opposite in Krita 4.2.8